# AJAX changing content of page does not work more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to load different views without reloading using JQUERY > AJAX. 
It works fine the first time but the second time it triggers the call and loads the page.

Here is the button I'm using:
First time:

```
<p><a href="{{ URL::route('onboarding-ajax', ['i' => '2']) }}" id="next-step" next-step-id="2">Start <i class="icon arrow-right"></i></a></p>
```

Second time:

```
<p><a href="{{ URL::route('onboarding-ajax', ['i' => '3']) }}" id="next-step" next-step-id="3" >Next</a></p>
```

Here is the script:

```
    <script>
    $('#next-step').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var that    = $(this),
            url     = that.attr('href'),
            type    = 'GET',
            step_id = that.attr('next-step-id'),
            width   = (step_id / 32)*100 + '%';

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,

            success: function(response) {
                $('#content-wrap').html(response.view);
                window.history.pushState({path:url},'',url);
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any idea what is being done wrong?

Comment: Is `#next-step` inside `#content-wrap`?

Comment: Thanks. Yes it is inside. @Amadan

Comment: I'm not great with DOM or jQuery, but maybe because it using an id, the script is bound to that element, and then does not realize there is a new element with the same id, since the page never reloads? if you change to `class="next-step"` and change the script to `$('.next-step')`, does that help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `#next-step` element is inside `#content-wrap`, it will disappear when you replace `#content-wrap` contents. If the new contents also have a `#next-step` inside it, it is a *different* element with the same ID, and will not have a `click` handler attached to it like the previous one did.

The easiest way to salvage it is to use a "live" handler - not on the `#next-step`, but on a parent. Try this:

```
$('#content-wrap').on('click', '#next-step', function (e) {
```

This tells `#content-wrap` to pay attention to a `click` event on a `#next-step`. Since you don't replace `#content-wrap` itself, this handler will persist, and will catch events even if `#next-step` is replaced.

Comment: Would changing to a class like I suggested in my comment also work?

Comment: @JasonKennaly: No. As long as the event handler is bound to an element that gets removed from the document, it doesn't matter which selector you use to access it.

Comment: Thank you so much this is great! I tried to add a pay attention on click on itself earlier obviously it wouldn't work. Good call on the "static" element. 
No will dig into how to make the previous load previous thing too..
@JasonKennaly had tried it before posting didn't work as explained by  amadan :-)

Comment: Hi, can I ask you to elaborate? I have this code: `$('body').click('[data-url]', function() { var lnk = $(this).attr("data-url");` As you see the variable's value is extracted from clicked element - it is hooked to `this`. How to handle the case?

Comment: @Peter: I am afraid I do not know what you are asking. I don't know what you are trying to do, I don't know what "handling the case" means to you, and I don't know what is the relation of your comment to this question. Please post a new question, with full details, a minimal self-contained code sample, and a description of what you want to do and how exactly your code is failing to do it.

Comment: Oh, I have already resolved my problem - thanks to answer supplied here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097417/multiple-semantic-ui-popups-with-target-element-defined-in-atribute-of-each-inst/35097790#35097790
Thank you for your response!