# multiple semantic-ui popups with target element defined in atribute of each instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, popup, semantic-ui

I have succesfully defined a popup for a clickable link element:

The element:

```
`<a href="{{URL::to('alerts')}}" data-tcs="#popup-1">Alerts Page</a>`
```

The script which triggers my popup (note the commented lines!)

```
$('[data-tcs]')
.popup({
// (default as in example provided on the S-UI, works well) 
// popup : $('#popup-1'),
// (attempt 1, doesn't work) 
// popup : $(this).data('tcs'),
// (attempt 2, doesn't work) 
    popup : $(this).attr('data-tcs'),
    on    : 'hover',
    delay: {
      show: 0,
      hide: 500
    },
    hoverable: true
});
```

The popup itself (irrelevant):

```
<div class="ui popup" id="popup-1"> 
  <h3>TANJ!</h3> 
  </div>
```

#### TO DO

Now the popup works well ONLY when the ID of target content is pointed directly, but...
I am about to put about 10 more popups and I want to use the same script to trigger them. 
**How I can point to the proper popup depending on the value of data-tcs attribute?**
My attempts were friutless.

Thx for all help.

The docs are here: 
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/examples

Comment: I am pretty sure you can use a class selector then narrow it down using `$(this)` judging from the documentation

Comment: Actually the main selector might need to be a class, the `$('[data-tcs])` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you need to pass instance specific data to any plugin options the easiest way is to wrap the initialization in an `each` loop

Then the `each` loop will expose the instance as `this`.

When you are trying to use `this` currently it is the `window` not the element

```
$('[data-tcs]').each(function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  $el.popup({    
    popup: $el.attr('data-tcs'),
    on: 'hover',
    delay: {
      show: 0,
      hide: 500
    },
    hoverable: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!